# Problem in sending data thourgh a view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have funciton where I select the data from DB and send it thourgh

```
    $this->db->select('*');

    $this->db->where('ativo', $ativo);
    $data['usuarios'] = $this->db->get('usuarios')->result();


    $sessao = $this->session->userdata('contas');
    if (!empty($sessao)) {
        $this->load->view('dashboard/Consultausuario_view', $data);
    }
```

In the view I am trying to load this data into a table using a foreach, but I am getting a ERRO message.

```
foreach ($usuario as $user) {

$arrayusuarios =json_decode(json_encode($user), true);
```

THE ERRO MESSAGE:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: usuario

Filename: dashboard/Consultausuario_view.php

Line Number: 89

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\local\acjum1\application\views\dashboard\Consultausuario_view.php
Line: 89
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\local\acjum1\application\controllers\Dashboard.php
Line: 219
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\local\acjum1\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: `usuarios` != `usuario`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the users as `usuarios`, not as `usuario`. So you should use the variable name `$usarios`.

```
foreach ($usuarios as $user) {
    $arrayusuarios = json_decode(json_encode($user), true);
}
```

Comment: Oh, my. So simple, thank you!